# Upgrade from Project Server 2007 to Project Server 2010

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2010

I am learning Project Server 2010 these days and want to know if I had to upgrade from an existing Project Server 2007 to 2010 version, how many days can it take?

Isn't it a day or at max 2 days job considering the following:

1. Current Project Server 2007 consists of one server farm with one SQL Server machine and one Project Server machine
2. No 3rd party web parts installation or customization has been made

Or it can take longer than that?

Answer (score 0):

> I had the Project Server 2010 and SharePoint Server 2010 demo virtual machine up and running; in 10min my PWA 2007 instance got upgraded to 2010!!! Yes you heard me, barely enough time for a coffee. Want a live demo come to New Orleans and see it yourself!
>
> -Christophe (he was product manager in the product group)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisfie/archive/2010/05/27/how-to-upgrade-from-project-server-2007-to-project-server-2010-in-10min.aspx

I have had similar experiences.  If you don't have any 3rd party apps or customizations, it is  a breeze.